# Atleast one drop down value is more than 0 from multiple drop downs - jQuery Validator

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit

Two different drop down selection with jQuery validate validation

Let's use below HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Within a group of three phone numbers, ensure at least one is complete.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
 
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<label for="post_title">Post Title: </label>
<input type="text" name="post_title" value="" id="post_title" placeholder="Enter Title Here" class="inputtxt">
<br/>
<label for="category">Post Category: </label>
<select name="category" id="category" class="postselection valid" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="0">Please Select Your Category</option>
<option value="101">Sports</option>
<option value="102">Startups</option>
<option value="103">Travel</option>
<option value="106">Weather</option>
<option value="107">Wisdom</option>
<option value="108">Writing</option>
</select>
<br/>
OR
<br/>
<label for="group_category">Group Category: </label>
<select name="group_category" id="group_category" aria-invalid="false" class="mygroup postselection valid">
<option value="0">Select one of your groups</option>
<option value="11">New Launch Updates</option>
<option value="12">Smile Groups</option>
<option value="13">Social Enterprise</option>
<option value="14">Developers Corner</option>
<option value="15">WordPress</option> 
</select>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
 post_title: {
  required: true
 },
    category: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".postselection"]
    },
    group_category: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".postselection"]
    }
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

======================================================================

We have 2 multiple drop down here and I want either one selected both of one and that value must be greater than zero.

By default all drop down selected with first option. So, require_from_group not throwing validation error any time and I must want selection which are not selected by default.

In short,

- Either one option selected from numbers of drop downs
- And that value must to zero (default selection)

(**Note:** Use JQuery validator for validation is compulsory)

Let me know if you want further explanation with code snippet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't really get what is the actual question here...

Comment: I just updated my question. please check now.

Upper code snippet is JQuery form submission
and below is HTML form